# Strategy for reading and understanding Node.js code

Tags: javascript, open-source, maintenance, node.js

Concretely I am looking at [this 2000 line file](https://github.com/postwait/node-amqp/blob/master/amqp.js) of what I will pretty arbitrarily call "mediocre" code.

- It's not well-commented
- variable names and function names seem consistently intelligent
- functions are not well-documented
- functions are good length

In short:  its lines and small structures are readable, but it's impossible to infer architecture or design at a glance.  Most code I've worked on can be described thusly, to be fair.

So I need to understand this.  And work on it.  This is an important skill in software development I'm still weak at, and it's extremely important when working in a nascent system.

So my question is, when encountering foreign code like this that I am employing as client code but now need to understand and modify, what is a quick strategy for having a good understanding?

Answer (score -1):

Does the code have tests? (there weren't any in that link). If it does that's a great place to start as the tests should tell you the expected behavior of each module.

If it doesn't then write some. Make an educated guess  about a function or group of functions and how it performs then write a test to verify if it works as you expect. When your ready to move on to changing the code you will have a set of tests which should help you modify the code without introducing new bugs,

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest a top-down approach:

1. Investigate the build system, including the versioning system, make sure you are not looking at "experimental" branch.
2. Investigate the overall structure of the code.
3. Investigate the structure, the test system uses and use the implemented tests to help you understand the code itself.
4. Investigate each module and ascertain its purpose and document it.
5. Now you should be able to pinpoint the module which needs changing.